# What can be done wrong changing the chain in a single speed?

Tags: chain, noise, tension

I changed the chain of my singlespeed. I though it was going to be something really simple and quick, but I was completely wrong...

I keep getting a lot of noise while I'm pedaling (unless I go really slow/downhill)

What I've done:

1. Remove the old chain (It had around 1500-2000km).
2. Measure the number of links and cut the new change to the same number.
3. Close the chain.
4. Adjust tension so it can be moved around 3-4cm in vertical direction.
5. Center the wheel.

The same in photos:

I ordered a singlespeed chain and I think it is the same as what I had, at least I don't see any difference. The silver chain is the new one:

[image: chain1]

[image: chain2]

Installed:

[image: upview]

[image: upview2]

Tension:

[image: tension1]

[image: tension2]

If I added tension the pedals would not move freely backwards, if I remove tension it feels too loose.

I tried first without lubing, and then when I heard so much noise I added some oil but didn't make much of a difference.

What am I missing? The noise is the all the time when I pedal in in the whole range of motion.

Added photos of the cog and chainring:

[image: cog1]

[image: cog2]

[image: chainring]

[image: chainring2]

Comment: Could you add a photo that shows the teeth of cogs? Most probably this is because the cogs are worn and don't match the new chain.

Comment: @ojs I just added the photos. Is it possible that in only 1500-2000km the cogs are so worn that need replacement? The bike was not so expensive when I bough it new (400€), but I expected some parts to last a lot more.

Comment: Do you have a coaster brake?  Did you reattach the reaction arm to the stay?   (may not have, and might not have removed it for a chain swap)

Comment: @Criggie I don't have a coaster brake. Just a flipflop hub singlespeed/fixie.

Comment: Wear on sprockets is accelerated by a worn chain, that’s what has probably happened here. Single speed chains tend to wear slower than derailleur chains because that are wider and don’t have to run with the sprockets misaligned, but the SS sprocket caries the chain all the time.

Comment: Is your new chain the correct width? From looking at the 2nd picture I'd say they're different, the shiny one looks narrower.

Comment: @Carel I can't notice any difference with my eyes. The specs of the one silver one (new) are: 1/2"x1/8" -112 links and pin length 8,6mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The photos show that the contact surfaces of the cogs have been worn to match the old chain. The new chain does not match them perfectly, which is the reason to the noise.

For some reason singlespeed seems to be much more sensitive than derailleur cogs. The good news is that if you can tolerate the noise and vibration for a while, the new chain and old cogs do wear to match each other. If you do not want to do this, replacing the freewheel should help.

Comment: Does flipping the cog help?  Or does that simply shift the problem to braking due to the wear ?

Comment: This is a freewheel (there are photos, look at them), so braking isn't a problem. What is a problem is that after flipping the freewheel works backwards.

Comment: @ojs : The ring and the cog don't really look that worn. The teeth of the ring are scratched in a couple of places though not excessively and they still have the correct shape (no shark teeth). And BTW  a SS chain should really last far more than 2000km

Comment: @Carel have you ever ridden singlespeed? As I wrote, for some reason singlespeed drivetrain becomes noisy much faster than derailleur drivetrain, even if the cogs do not look that worn. 2000km isn't that much but on the other hand cheap bikes often have parts chosen for short term cost savings, not durability.

Comment: @ojs I have a 900€ SS with a flip hub which doesn't make any noise after 2000+ km and still with the first chain. So yes, it's probably the quality of the parts that's important. I tend to keep an ear for noises, following the principle of 'Noisy machine, bad machine!'

Comment: @Carel try replacing the chain. As far as I understand, the OP's old chain was quiet too.

Comment: @ojs We'll see when it comes to that. It's still below the stretch limit.

Comment: I just tried to use the fixed side of the flipflop hub and it doesn't make any sound. So definitely is a problem from the cog.