# What do I need to replace my singlespeed freewheel cog?

Tags: freewheel, sprocket

As I learned in [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/54325/what-can-be-done-wrong-changing-the-chain-in-a-single-speed) question, the cog of my freewheel are damaged and should be replaced.

I've been searching for some information but I'm still not sure of what I need. At the beginning I though I just needed to search for a cog like this with 1/8" like my chain:
[image: cog]

But reading the description it seems like it's only for fixed gears, so I was completely worng. Searching for more items under the single speed category in the website everything looked like that.

What do I need to buy as replacement?

This is how what I have now:
[image: my cog]

As tools a I just have the basics, when i search for freewheel remover I see hundreds of different things like this:
[image: tool1]
[image: tool2]
[image: tool3]
 ...

How can I know what I need?

Update with photo of the wheel:
[image: freewheel]

Comment: You have a flip flop hub.  If the fixed side is not worn, then consider flipping it and riding on the fixed side, to see if the noises reduce or go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Park tool has a guide to figuring out what type of free hub/freewheel you have, and what tool you need to get it off.

https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/determining-cassette-freewheel-type.

With that knowledge you should be able to to figure out what type of replacement freewheel/spocket you need (or two, as you have a flip-flop hub).

Update:

Also see the [Sheldon Brown page on Freewheels](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/freewheels.html).

Depending on what the freewheel thread turns out to be, you should be able to get a replacement freewheel that has a more standard lockring.

You might consider creating a 'bodged' tool to get the current freewheel off. You might be able to 'drift' the lockring loose by tapping the ring around with an old screwdriver and hammer.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I need a freewheel + it's extractor, but I can't find any extractor with 8 notches as my current freewheel has.

Comment: Did the Park Tool guide not help? Can you provide a well lit photo of the FW with the wheel out of the bike? It's a bit hard to see the lock-ring in the pic you provided.

Comment: sorry I didn't had time to extract the wheel. I just uploaded a new photo. I can't see any parktool  tool with those 8 notches nor find something similar in the amazon from my country.

Comment: I have a similar looking 8-notch freewheel. It is compatible with 4-notch tool, leaving other 4 unused.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you use the 4-notch tool with rectangular form (fr-6 in parktool) or square form (f4-8 in parktool)?

Comment: Park FR-3, -4 and -8 are 24, 40 and 32mm in diameter respectively. You'll need the one which is closest the diameter of your lockring.