# How long does a freewheel cog last?

Tags: chain, freewheel, noise, sprocket

4 months I asked this question when I changed my chain:
[What can be done wrong changing the chain in a single speed?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/54325/what-can-be-done-wrong-changing-the-chain-in-a-single-speed) and the solution was to change the freewheel cog.

I decided to "invest" in the not cheapest model. I just found two possibilities the halo clickster for around 50€ and the white industries for around 120€, or the same I had some kind of no brand for 20€.

I decided to get the mid range halo clickster. Well after just 3 months and around 3000km I decided as maintenance that it was time to change the chain. So I put the new chain and I get the same kind of noise.

Is it normal that it is already worn out? Does it make sense to pay more for just a little amount of km?

This is how it looks:
[image: cog]

And this is how it sounds, just when I give it some power.
https://streamable.com/hfqlp
The tension from the chain is not high, i can move it in both directions at least 2cm.

Comment: Doesn't seem that noisy to me.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It could be worse, but for me is really annoying, my bike as a single speed (and i tried to have it well maintained)is usually really quiet and I like to pedal at a high cadence which makes makes it even louder.

Answer (score 3):

3000km is enough of a wear life for a singlespeed freewheel that I would say there's nothing necessarily wrong here.

One way to check wear is just looking at the side of the freewheel teeth that contacts the chain versus the side that doesn't. The more asymmetry, the more wear.

If you ride it like it is, it probably will break in and get quieter, but what's happening there is your chain's pitch elongating to "catch up" to the freewheel, which isn't necessarily a good thing.

I don't have experience with the Halo one but it sounds like it might be a little too boutiquey for its own good. The cheaper Shimano freewheels are pretty excellent at reliability, wear life, and not being too painful to replace when they do wear out.

Comment: I had considered one of those, but looking at the comments in a big we like chainreactioncycles it looks like they are really bad, some people saying they fail with under 1000km. That is really disappointing.

Comment: Weird, I've had good luck with them. It seems like cheap, good BMX freewheels have become an endangered species. Maybe because real BMX bikes don't use them much anymore.

Comment: Is there any value in flipping the cog?  Would OP get a better surface for the new chain to rest on?  If the cog is threadded it should just spin on, less likely for a cassette conversion though.

Comment: @Criggie Wouldn’t the freewheel work in reverse then?

Comment: @MaplePanda at the time I guessed incorrectly that it was a single cog trapped inside some spacers on a normal freehub body.   My alfine 11 drive sprocket could be flipped in place, and the chain line was unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced mine today,  I got a higher quality than what I used to have.  The one I had was cheap quality and failed on me with only 300 km , lots of knocking sounds coming out of it. Honestly higher quality less stress,  and more peace of mind

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  With a lifespan of only 300km, it sounds like you had a substandard or defective component, and I don't know if that provides a useful number.  It would also help if you identified the brand, and what the _expected_ lifespan of it was.